# Number of paths with 1,2,... crosses over a point $m$ between 0 and $x$ in a random walk of $n$ steps

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

Suppose we have a random walk starting from origin and ending at $x$ with $n$ steps, where the set of points is integers on the number line and the steps allowed are 'right' and 'left'. We know that the total paths satisfying the above statement is
$$W(x,n)=\binom{n}{\frac{n+x}{2}}$$
I want to find the number of paths with 1 cross, 2 crosses, and so on over $m$ which is a point located between $0$ and $x$. I figured out 
$$W(m−1,t)W(2,2)W(x−(m+1),n−t−2)$$
is the total number of paths with 1 cross but I can't generalize it to more crosses.

Comment: What is the space of points & what are the possible steps ?

Comment: 1D and only left and right with equal probabilities. $p=q=1/2$